# value keeps resetting when re-calling function

Tags: c#

Every time I re-call my `GameStart` function, `ToastersHealth` goes back to 500 because it resets the value (as you can see in the program comments) any advice? I want the value to only be 500 the first time and keep decreasing as the player shoots

```
public static void Main(string[] args) //Main Function
{
    GameStart(args);
}

public static void GameStart(string[] args) //GameStart Function
{
    Console.WriteLine("Choose a gun to shoot at Toaster... ");
    Console.Write("rocket/sniper/: ");
    string playersGunChoice = Console.ReadLine();
    Random randomweapondmg = new Random();
    int weapondmg = 0;
    switch (playersGunChoice.ToLower())
    {
        case "rocket":
            Console.WriteLine("You chose a rocket.");
            weapondmg = randomweapondmg.Next(75, 200);
            Console.WriteLine("Your rocket does " + weapondmg + " to Toaster.");
            break;
        case "sniper":
            Console.WriteLine("You chose a sniper.");
            weapondmg = randomweapondmg.Next(50, 150);
            Console.WriteLine("Your sniper does " + weapondmg + " to Toaster.");
            break;
        default:
            Console.WriteLine("You didn't choose a gun.");
            break;
    }
    int ToasterHealth = 500; // I don't want ToasterHealth to reset to 500 everytime the GameStart function gets called
    int ToastersLeftHp = ToasterHealth - weapondmg;
    Console.WriteLine("Toaster has " + ToastersLeftHp + " healthpoints left.");
    if (ToastersLeftHp != 0)
        do
        {
            GameStart(args);
        } while (ToastersLeftHp < 0);

    if (ToastersLeftHp == 0)
        Console.WriteLine("You killed Toaster!");
    else if (ToastersLeftHp < 100)
        Console.WriteLine("Toaster is almost dead! He has " + ToastersLeftHp + " healthpoints left.");
    else if (ToastersLeftHp < 0)
        Console.WriteLine("You killed Toaster!");
}
```

Comment: are you familiar with the term `Scope` you need to declare a static variable outside of the methods at the class level default it there and then remove it from the GameStart method here is something that will make for some good reading and understanding [C Variable and Method Scope](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx)

Comment: thank you,. I need t o read up on classes too. thats sort of what I was thinking but I kept getting compiling errors when it was outside of my function

Comment: Because your method is recursive (it calls itself), you need to either A, pass the ToasterHealth in as parameter along with your array of arguments, or B., wrap your 'int ToasterHealth = 500;' within a condition that can only be true within the first iteration.  The issue is that you keep reinitializing the ToasterHealth within the method body and there is no conditions to prevent it.

Comment: so I would have to make multiple loops or make it a class? is there any easy way of making the condition true only once

Comment: Another option would be to create a containing class object (eg. PlayerStats) which encapsulates the ToasterHealth and any other value that you need to persist between iterations.  You can then create an instance of this class, initialize it's default values and pass it as an object into the method.  Then in the method, you update the values accordingly.  This option would have a number of benefits. For one thing, persistence of values is easier to manage. Another would be as @Servy below implied.  It would reduce the code within the method body and help reduce 'spaghetti code'

Comment: i sorta get what you mean, so I would research on how to create a class, add toasterhealth values there (and whatever other ones I may need in the future), create/call the class it in my game program to get the values, I'm still very new and need to research this stuff so

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to run before you can walk.  I recommend you do a bit of research into the concepts of Object Oriented Programming.  That would be a very good first step.  Any time you use the .dot accessor (eg Console -> .  WriteLine()), you are accessing the method or property of a class object.  In the case of the included example I provided in this statement, Console would be the class and WriteLine() would be a method call of that class.

Comment: mhmm, I am still learning the basic terms (kind of confused on what arguments  are, what everyone means by recursivness/iterations, etc)

Comment: @ally, I have update my provided solution below to gear it around your requirements. Copy the entire program block and paste it over your existing program block. Please let me know if this it is more what you are looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that you are subtracting from the wrong property. Try doing your weapon damage subtraction like this.

```
    player.TakeDamage(weapondmg);
```

...and just remove toastersLeftHp from your method and replace with player.CurrentHealth.  Moving the damage dealing portion of your code to the player would also allow you to add damage modifiers like armor.

```
class Player
{
    public CurrentHealth { get; set;}
    public Player()
    {
        CurrentHealth = 500;
    }
    public TakeDamage(int WeaponDamage)
    {
        CurrentHealth -= WeaponDamage;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your loop is weird:

```
if (ToastersLeftHp != 0)
    do
    {
        GameStart(args);
    } while (ToastersLeftHp < 0);
```

If `ToastersLeftHp` ever becomes negative, that's an infinite loop.  Definitely not what you want.  Try putting a loop around your entire game logic:

```
public static void GameStart(string[] args) //GameStart Function
{
    int ToasterHealth = 500; // happens just once, before the loop starts

    do {
        Console.WriteLine("Choose a gun to shoot at Toaster... ");
        Console.Write("rocket/sniper/: ");
        // all the stuff to make the gun hurt Toaster here
    } while (ToasterHealth > 0);

    DisplayMessage("You killed Toaster!");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare int ToasterHealth = 500 as a class variable and not as a variable inside your GameStart function.

Comment: That would make trying to understand/debug this program, given its recursive code, a giant mess.

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand the comment. What would make it a giant mess?

Comment: Imagine stepping through the code that the OP has and trying to understand what's going on at every point in time.  The recursive (and iterative) implementation of an inherently non-recursive algorithm just makes the whole thing a big mess.  Trying to understand what's going on is dramatically more complex than it needs to be.  As a rule recursive methods tend not to play nice with external state shared between each invocation.

Answer (score -1):

In order not to reset ToasterHealth each time you call GameStart, it needs to be defined outside of GameStart.

```
    static int ToasterHealth = 500;
    public static void GameStart(string[] args) //GameStart Function
    {
        int ToastersLeftHp = ToasterHealth - weapondmg;
    }
```

If you want to monitor ToasterHealth to see where is it being reset, use this and put your breakpoint on the _ToasterHealth = value; line.

```
    static int _ToasterHealth = 500;
    private int ToasterHealth
    {
        get { return _ToasterHealth; }
        set
        {
            _ToasterHealth = value;
        }
    }
```

Be sure you do *not* set _ToasterHealth directly anywhere, only through the ToasterHealth property.  I think you will find that the reason ToasterHealth does not go down is that you never subtract anything from it.

Comment: I just tried defining it outside of the function (http://pastebin.com/VCEeAXxJ) still doesn't work

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"?  Do you have debugging capabilities?  If so, then you need to check and see if Main() is being called each time you restart the game.  If so, there's no programmatic way you can tell if the game is "starting" or "restarting" outside of passing in a command line value or storing to a config file.

Comment: If you have verified that Main is only called once, use the debugger to see if your value is hitting the code to decrement ToasterHealth.  If it is, and it is still being reset each time you call GameStart, change ToasterHealth to a property and out a breakpoint in the setter.

Comment: By the way, where are you actually subtracting from ToasterHealth?  It looks like you are decrementing from ToastersLeftHp, so *that* is the variable you should have outside GameStart.

Answer (score -1):

ally, the code here should get you off on the right foot.  The code should execute without error.  Simply replace your program class with the following, if you have any issues, don't hesitate to ask questions:

**EDIT:** *Modified provided example based on OPs solution requirements. Also included a weapons class object as an option to extend the game future allowing flexibility in weapon types, ammo types and damage potentials. Consider it homework. (Hint: used almost exactly the same way that I'm using the enemy object.)*

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        GameStart(args);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This method starts the game.
    /// Note: You can change the method GameStart signature to accept no parameters instead and still
    /// get the exact same results. ( eg.  Change GameStart signature from GameStart(string[] args) to GameStart(). )
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="args">Irrelevant array or parameters.  They are not presently used within the method.</param>
    static void GameStart(string[] args)
    {
        // Create a new player
        Player player = new Player();

        // Create a new toaster enemy with a life of 500. (To demonstrate how to use the Enemy class to create different
        // enemy types, comment or uncomment the enemy initialization lines below.)
        Enemy enemy = new Enemy("Toaster", 500);
        //Enemy enemy = new Enemy("King Toaster", 1000);
        //Enemy enemy = new Enemy("Gargantuan Toaster", 10000);

        // Until the enemy is dead, we will choose a gun or ammo type, and attack the enemy.
        while (enemy.Health > 0)
        {
            // Ask the player to choose a gun in order to kill the enemy.
            DisplayMessage(string.Format("Choose a gun to shoot at {0}...", enemy.EnemyType));
            DisplayMessage("rocket/sniper: ");

            // Get the gun selection from the player.
            player.PlayerGunChoice = Console.ReadLine();

            // Add a new line between the text to make it more easily readable.
            DisplayMessage(string.Empty);

            // Based on the player's gun selection, set the players weapon damage. 
            switch (player.PlayerGunChoice)
            {
                case "rocket":
                    DisplayMessage("You chose a rocket.");
                    player.WeaponDamage = GetRandomWeaponDamage(75, 200);
                    DisplayMessage(string.Format("Your rocket does {0} to {1}.", player.WeaponDamage, enemy.EnemyType));
                    break;
                case "sniper":
                    DisplayMessage("You chose a sniper.");
                    player.WeaponDamage = GetRandomWeaponDamage(50, 150);
                    DisplayMessage(string.Format("Your sniper does {0} to {1}.", player.WeaponDamage, enemy.EnemyType));
                    break;
                default:
                    DisplayMessage("You didn't choose a gun.");
                    break;
            }

            // Subtract the enemy's health by the player's current weapon damage.
            enemy.Health -= player.WeaponDamage;

            // Is the enemy health less than 0? If so, set it to 0.  If an enemy is already 0, then it's dead, it can't lose anymore health.
            // Otherwise, is the enemy health less than 100? If so, let the player know that the enemy is almost dead.
            if (enemy.Health < 0)
                enemy.Health = 0;
            else if (enemy.Health < 100)
                DisplayMessage(string.Format("{0} is almost dead!", enemy.EnemyType, enemy.Health));

            // Tell the player what the current health is of the enemy.
            DisplayMessage(string.Format("{0} has {1} healthpoints left.", enemy.EnemyType, enemy.Health));

            // Wait for the player to read the message displayed before clearing the screen. We do this to keep the message window clutter free and readable.
            Console.ReadLine();

            // The damage done and health of the enemy has been read by the player. So lets clear the screen for the next attack.
            ClearDisplay();
        }

        // Success!  The health of the enemy has reached 0, so lets let the player know that the enemy is dead. 
        DisplayMessage(string.Format("You killed {0}!\n", enemy.EnemyType));

        // End the program when the player has hit a key.
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Method used to get a random weapon damage based on the minimum and maximum damage potential of the weapon.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="min">Minimum possible damage.</param>
    /// <param name="max">Maximum possible damage</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    static int GetRandomWeaponDamage(int min, int max)
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        return random.Next(min, max);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Simply a wrapper method that calls Console.WriteLine to display a message to the console window. This is for the purpose of understanding program flow.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="text">The method to display on the console window.</param>
    static void DisplayMessage(string text)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(text);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Simply a wrapper method that calls Console.Clear to clear the message window. This is for the purpose of understanding program flow.
    /// </summary>
    static void ClearDisplay()
    {
        Console.Clear();
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// A player class object which encompasses the player gun choice and weapon damage.
/// </summary>
class Player
{
    public int WeaponDamage { get; set; }

    public string PlayerGunChoice { get; set; }

    public Player()
    {
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// The enemy class object which encompasses the enemy of a defined type and designated health.  
/// This object provides the option to create different types of enemies with varying differences in health.
/// (eg. King Toaster with 1000 maximum health points or Gargantuan Toaster with 10000 maximum health points.)
/// </summary>
class Enemy
{
    public string EnemyType { get; set; }

    public int Health { get; set; }

    public Enemy()
    {
    }

    public Enemy(string enemyType, int health)
    {
        EnemyType = enemyType;
        Health = health;
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// The weapon class object which encompasses the weapon type, ammo type, minimum and maximum damage potential of the weapon.
/// </summary>
class Weapon
{
    public string WeaponType { get; set; }  // (eg. Rocket Launcher, Sniper Rifle, Shotgun, Crossbow)

    public string AmmoType { get; set; }    // (eg. Explosive Rounds, buckshots, Armor piercing)

    public int MinimumDamage { get; set; }  

    public int MaximumDamage { get; set; }

    public Weapon()
    {
    }

    public Weapon(string weaponType, string ammoType, int minimumDamage, int maximumDamage)
    {
        WeaponType = weaponType;
        AmmoType = ammoType;
        MinimumDamage = minimumDamage;
        MaximumDamage = maximumDamage;
    }
}
```

Comment: I compiled it and the Toasters healthpoints still resets to 500, but I learned a few new things, thank you

Comment: ally, you are still looking at the wrong property.  ToasterHealth could properly be called your "max health".  That is the amount of health your character starts with.  "Current health" is toastersLeftHp and that is the only property that you are subtracting your damage from.  Define toastersLeftHp inside your Player class.  or, if you need to use toasterHealth as your "current health", remember to subtract from it at the same time that you subtract from toastersLeftHp.

Comment: I have updated the example that I've provided to properly reduce the health of the enemy toaster.  Please try it again and let me know if this is closer to your idea of a working and acceptable solution @ally