# Inheritance - storing objects list<class> with loops C#

Tags: c#, list, constructor, multiple-inheritance

I'm stuck one an exercise which is very important to understand for my soon come final exam, in a basic C# course.

I have an issue that I can't describe in words. So I'll show you with code and perhaps then you might help me. 
I've been stuck on this, not being able to solve it, for a long time. Cuz of that, I don't want any copy paste code. I want to understand it. So please enlighten me where I've failed.

Explanation what I want to do. 
I want to create a *dart game 501*. So first I *add players*, they throw their darts, you get the *score after each turn* announced, then when one player reach *501 points*, the game *announce the winner and all of his throws*.

My idea of approaching the problem is to have an add player loop, which terminates (I got this fixed already). 
Once you done creating the players(list elements), then you'll execute the methods with a foreach loop running all the players in the player list, *executing the objects one at a time* and finally **Here is my real problem:** storing all their *scores* in another *list*.

**Here we go with the code**

The *list*.

```
private List<Player> players = new List<Player>();  //This list is fine
```

Here is the *loop*.

```
foreach (Player dartThrows in players) //My loop
             {
               dartThrows.DoThrow();
               dartThrows.GetScore();
             }
```

SubClass1(named *Player*)

```
public List<Darts> dartList = new List<Darts>(); //<--HERE IS THE PROBLEM
```

Just some random constructors and methods.

**The throw method. It's not an issue but I typed it down to give you an idea**

```
public void DoThrow()
            {
                           var tries = 3;

        for (int i = 0; i < tries; i++) 
        {
             //No problems here just int read-user input data
        }
AddDarts(int a, int b, intc)

    }
```

**Here lies all my problems, it would make my life so much easier if this could get solved.**

```
        public void AddDarts(Darts toDartList) 
    {

        dartList.Add(toDartList); 
    }
```

SubClass2 (*Darts*)

**Here are my constructors**

```
private int dartOne;
private int dartOne;
private int dartOne;
```

**Here is my method**

```
        public Darts(int DartOne, int DartTwo, int DartThree) 
    {
        dartOne = DartOne;
        dartTwo = DartTwo;
        dartThree = DartThree;

    }
```

Best regards Marcus Johansson

**Here is my full program**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Game game = new Game();
        game.PlayGame();
    }
}
class Game
{

    private List<Player> players = new List<Player>();
    private List<Player> computers = new List<Player>();

    public void AddPlayer(string newPlayers)
    {
        players.Add(new Player(newPlayers));
    }
    public void AddComputer(string newComputer) 
    {
        computers.Add(new Player(newComputer));
    }
    static string UpperCaseFirst(string s)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
        return char.ToUpper(s[0]) + s.Substring(1);
    }
    public void PlayGame() 
    {
        bool noWinner = false;
        bool stopLoop = false;

        Console.WriteLine("<<<WELCOME TO DART 501>>>");

        Console.WriteLine("\nPress [S] to start game!");
        Console.Beep();
        Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Clear();

        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter name of players and type [D]ator for adding NPC\nType [S]top to start the game");
            string addPlayer = Console.ReadLine();
            string FirstUpperLetter = UpperCaseFirst(addPlayer);
            if (FirstUpperLetter == "Stop" || FirstUpperLetter == "S")
            {
                stopLoop = true;
            }
            if (FirstUpperLetter == "D" || FirstUpperLetter == "Dator")
            {
                string computer = FirstUpperLetter;
                AddComputer(computer);
            }
            else
            {
                AddPlayer(FirstUpperLetter);
            }

        } while (stopLoop == false) ;
        players.RemoveAt(players.Count - 1);

        do 
        {
            Console.Clear();

            foreach (Player arrowThrows in players)
            {
                noWinner = true;
                Console.WriteLine("\n~~~Starting Round~~~~");
                arrowThrows.DoThrow();
                Console.WriteLine("This round you got {0}", arrowThrows.CalculatePoints());
                if (arrowThrows.Score > 501)
                {
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.WriteLine("<<<WE HAVE A WINNER>>>");
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
                    Console.WriteLine("...The winner is: ");
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} He made these epic throws: ", arrowThrows.Name);
                    foreach(Arrows finalResult in arrowThrows.arrowList)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(finalResult);
                        Console.ReadLine();
                    }
                    noWinner = false;
                }

            }
            foreach (Player computerThrows in computers)
            {
                computerThrows.RandomThrow();
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
            }
        }while(noWinner == true);

    }

}
class Player
{
    public List<Arrows> arrowList = new List<Arrows>();
    public List<int> ScoreBoard = new List<int>();

    public Player() { }

    public int Score { get; set; }

    public Player(int score)
    {
        Score = score;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Player(string name) 
    {
        Name = name;
    }
    public int RoundScore { get; set; }
    public void RandomThrow() 
    {
        Random rndComp = new Random();

        Console.WriteLine("...Loading Npc_throw.exe");
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(300);
        int random1 = rndComp.Next(0, 60);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(300);
        int random2 = rndComp.Next(0, 60);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(300);
        int random3 = rndComp.Next(0, 60);

        Console.WriteLine("Random computer got this random score {0}", random1 + random2 + random3);
        arrowList.Add(new Arrows(random1, random2, random3));
    }

    public void DoThrow() 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("###{0} make your throws###", Name);
        var tries = 3;

        for (int i = 0; i < tries; i++) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nEnter score for {0} arrow", i + 1);
            string arrowScore = Console.ReadLine();
            int addScore = int.Parse(arrowScore);

            while(-1 > addScore || 61 < addScore) 
            {

                Console.WriteLine("\nInvalid score! Enter a score between 0-60/n<<<You may type [R]andom or [R] for a random score>>>");
                arrowScore = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();

                if (arrowScore == "R" || arrowScore == "RANDOM")
                {
                    Random rnd = new Random();
                    addScore = rnd.Next(0, 60);
                    goto start;
                }
                else
                {
                    addScore = int.Parse(arrowScore);
                }

            }

        start:
        ScoreBoard.Add(addScore);
        }
        ScoreBoard.ToArray();

        arrowList.Add(new Arrows(ScoreBoard[0],ScoreBoard[1], ScoreBoard[2]));
    }
    public int CalculatePoints() 
    {
        Score = ScoreBoard.Sum();
        return Score;
        }
    public void AddArrows(Arrows toArrowList) 
    {
        toArrowList.ToString();
        arrowList.Add(new Arrows(ScoreBoard[0], ScoreBoard[1], ScoreBoard[2])); 
    }
}
class Arrows 
{
    private int arrowOne;
    private int arrowTwo;
    private int arrowThree;

    public int score { get; set; }

    public Arrows(int ArrowOne, int ArrowTwo, int ArrowThree) 
    {
        arrowOne = ArrowOne;
        arrowTwo = ArrowTwo;
        arrowThree = ArrowThree;

    }
    public int GetScore() 
    {
        return arrowOne + arrowTwo + arrowThree;
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0}-1:st arrow: {1}-2:nd arrow: {2}- 3:rd arrow: {3}", GetScore(), arrowOne, arrowTwo, arrowThree);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: TL;DR... you say "problem here"... but you never clearly stay what "problem" is... Also title contains "multiple inheritance" which first of all does not exist in C# and also never even mentioned in the post from what I can tell.

Comment: Best to start with the error(s) you get when you try to run your program, or the unexpected behavior that happens when you run it, the relevant code that throws the exception(s) or has a logic error, and what you intend for it to do.

Comment: what are dartOne, dartTwo, dartThree ?

Comment: I wish I knew what the problem is so I could be more specific. There is no errors or any such thing. The problem is **storing values in another list<class> in a sub class* and doing so using a *loop*. dartOne, dartTwo, dartThree are objects, which my teacher told me to implement.

Comment: Please take this as merely constructive criticism.  If you aren't getting the core fundamentals of your course by the time your exam rolls around, you shouldn't be passing the exam.

Comment: @JamesShaw That is usually my approach. I know that I'm lacking alot really. I've been advancing a bit too fast just studying without really understanding and grasping the core.

Comment: Perhaps the answer I posted at the following link, might help get you on the right track.  Please excuse the fact that it was voted down. This was because the original suggested solution didn't provide the OP with the answer that he was after.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/29422932/1649952

Comment: Thanks for that article it made me think, I thought I had a solution, but it didn't work perhaps it was too complext solution for me. All I need is to display **The winning players** score with all his throws. Not just the TOTAL score, but each individual scores, **scores in a list**

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your approach, is your utilizing a `List`.  This collection has no unique information, simply a grouping of data.  Which would have me recommend either a `Tuple`, `Dictionary`, `KeyValuePair`, or a clean *Data Model*.

Without the requirements are approaches may not be viable.  Your issue stems from persistence related issues.  Your multiple inheritance title is also incorrect, C# only allows a single `class` to be inherited.

What I would potentially do would be:

```
public class Player
{
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public string Throw { get; set; }
     public string Points { get; set; }
}
```

What this does, is incredibly beneficial.  The above `class` represents a specific *Model*.  When your method is called for a throw you apply said results.  Then when you calculate the score you iterate through the `List<Player>` for a specific person or all and display the output.

I'm not going to write your application, but think of it like this:

1. Player Registers
2. Player Turn
3. Player Throws
4. Play Scored
5. Store Player Result
6. Repeat Steps two through five, three times.
7. Display Output: Player, Throw, Score, and Total Score

By utilizing that model, you hold the relative information for your outcome.  This conceptual notion is important for Object Oriented Programming.

Comment: Thank ypu so astronomically much! I'll read up more on the content you mentioned and implement your solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Dictionary to save scores for each player

```
Dictionary<Player, List<int>> playerScores = new Dictionary<Player, List<int>>();

playerScores.Add(player1, new List<int>()); //init dictionary with a new player
playerScores[player1].Add(number); //add a value to the list associated with the player
```

So each player has a list of scores.

Comment: Thanks alot. I'll try this aswell and look up more on the object.